# What does the checkbox next to the podcasts in iTunes do?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

In the Podcasts screen in iTunes, there is a checkbox next to every episode (right in front of the name). In my case, they are all checked (except for episodes which have not been downloaded yet; for them, the box is greyed out).

What does this checkbox do?

Comment: Actually, everything in the library has this checkbox, not just podcasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During playback, iTunes skips over unchecked songs. You can also disable syncing of unchecked songs to iPod/iPhone etc.

Comment: I see. How do I do disable syncing?

Comment: When your iPhone is connected, in the first tab (`Summary`), under the *Options* section, there's a checkbox to only sync ticked songs and videos.